# Is this caused by insufficient memory?

Tags: java, linux, memory-management, out-of-memory

This problem occurred when I used chipyard to compile Boom. Is this because of insufficient memory? I am running on a 1 core 2G cloud server.

> /bin/bash: line 1:  9986 Killed                  java -Xmx8G -Xss8M
> -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/generators/rocket-chip/sbt-launch.jar
> -Dsbt.sourcemode=true -Dsbt.workspace=/home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/tools ";project utilities; runMain utilities.GenerateSimFiles -td
> /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig
> -sim verilator"
> /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/common.mk:86: recipe for target
> '/home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/sim_files.f'
> failed
> make: *** [/home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/sim_files.f]
> Error 137

When I adjusted the memory to 4G, this appeared.

> Done elaborating. OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
> os::commit_memory(0x00000006dc3b7000, 97148928, 0) failed;
> error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
> Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 97148928 bytes for committing reserved memory.
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
> /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/hs_err_pid2876.log /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/common.mk:97: recipe for target
> 'generator_temp' failed make: *** [generator_temp] Error 1

Should I adjust to 8G memory, or through what command to increase the memory size that the process can use?

When I adjusted the memory to 16G, this appeared.

> /bin/bash: line 1:  2642 Killed                  java -Xmx8G -Xss8M
> -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/generators/rocket-chip/sbt-launch.jar
> -Dsbt.sourcemode=true -Dsbt.workspace=/home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/tools ";project tapeout; runMain barstools.tapeout.transforms.GenerateTopAndHarness -o
> /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.top.v
> -tho /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.harness.v
> -i /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.fir
> --syn-top ChipTop --harness-top TestHarness -faf /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.anno.json
> -tsaof /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.top.anno.json
> -tdf /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/firrtl_black_box_resource_files.top.f
> -tsf /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.top.fir
> -thaof /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.harness.anno.json
> -hdf /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/firrtl_black_box_resource_files.harness.f
> -thf /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.harness.fir
> --infer-rw --repl-seq-mem -c:TestHarness:-o:/home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.top.mems.conf
> -thconf /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig.harness.mems.conf
> -td /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/sims/verilator/generated-src/chipyard.TestHarness.LargeBoomConfig
> -ll error" /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/common.mk:123: recipe for target 'firrtl_temp' failed make: *** [firrtl_temp] Error
> 137

Comment: The original command is make CONFIG=LargeBoomConfig. Did I change to make CONFIG=LargeBoomConfig -Xmx6G -Xss3G?

Comment: yep, or by command line when you execute the process: `java -Xms3G -Xmx6G yourprogam.java`

Comment: Note that by my mistake was writing -Xss when it should be -Xms  (the first one's for the heap, not involved for now here)

Comment: `-Xms3G` -- minimum of 3GB allocated for the JVM
`-Xmx6G` -- maximum of 6GB allocated for the JVM

Comment: make: invalid option -- 'G'. this occurs.

Comment: wow, that picky one. Try with `-Xms3g` and `-Xmx6g`

Comment: make: invalid option -- 'g'

Comment: where exactly is throwing that? -Xms3g is totally valid... how are you launching it?

This should be valid 100% :`java -Xmx6g -Xms4g -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/generators/rocket-chip/sbt-launch.jar`

Comment: make CONFIG=LargeBoomConfig -Xmx6g -Xms3g

Comment: could you manually launch it that way? JUst copy-paste it

Comment: What do you mean? make CONFIG=LargeBoomConfig can run for a period of time, and then an insufficient memory error occurs.

Comment: Regardless that config does whatever it does, the command it's executing is exactly that: `java -Xmx6g -Xms4g -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar /home/cuiyujie/workspace/Boom/chipyard/generators/rocket-chip/sbt-launch.jar`  (with other params) Look at the first line of the trace, that's your lauched command

Comment: What I'm trying to say is to manually execute that command without relying on the CONFIG thins

Comment: Check first by executing `top` in order see your hosts' resources and guarantee there's still free memory for you program

Comment: Also, just to be sure...this isn't docker deployed, right?

Comment: Tencent Cloud Server. Similar to Amazon Cloud Server

Comment: Okay, but does not define a default maximum, I hope. Commented the docker issue cause by default containers are assigned 4GB max, and it must me reconfigured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Short answer : yes***

---

`Error 137` is thrown when your **host runs out of memory**.

> *"I am running on a 1 core **2G** cloud server"*

When you try to assign **8GB** to the JVM, `OOM-Killer` says ***"no-no, f... no way"***, and kicks in sending a **`SIGKILL`**; *This Killer is a proactive process that jumps into saving the system when its memory level goes too low, by killing the **resource-abusive** processes*.

In this case, the abusive process (*very abusive, indeed*) is your java program, **which is trying to allocate more than(*)** **4 times the maximum available memory in your host**.

[*Exit Codes With Special Meanings*](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#FTN.AEN23629)

[image]

```
                 [error code 137 --> kill -9] (SIGKILL)
```

You should either:

- Assign at max ~*1.2GB - 1.5GB* to your process. (*and keep your fingers crossed*)
- **Change your host for something a little powerful/bigger if you do require that much memory for your process.**
- *Check if you really require 8GB for that process*.

---

*Also note that the given params are error-prone: Xmx8G -Xss8M means a maximum of 8GB and a minimum of 8M for the heap. This should be closer, as **Xmx8G - Xms4G***

**As the free memory won't be 2GB either, but something in between 1.6-1.8 GB*